# Why does even and odd reciprocal functions look different?

Tags: functions

For example, $y=x^{1/4}$ and $y=x^{1/3}$ look different?

For $y=x^{1/4}$ it does not have negative y and x values meanwhile the odd function has it. Shouldn’t both of the functions not have negative values as we cannot square root a negative x value as it would not be a real number?

Comment: Consider the cube root of $8$ and that of $-8$.

Comment: It's true that negative values don't have real square roots, but why would you think that's an argument for concluding odd roots of negative values shouldn't exist?

Comment: Agree with @runway44 --- note that squareroots are "even" roots as there is implied 2 as the index of the radical in squareroot case.

Comment: $(-1)^{(2n+1)}=-1\space$ and $\space(-1)^{2n}=1$... So the ${1\over{2n+1}}$ roots of negative numbers will always have a real solution while the ${1\over2n}$ roots of a negative number will always be, by necessity, complex valued.

Comment: It may help to consider the equations $x=y^4$ and $x=y^3$.